# How to launch gnome-panel on 22.04?

Tags: 22.04, gnome-panel

I just upgraded my desktop from 20.04 to 22.04 and `gnome-panel` refuses to start. In 20.04, I just needed to type `gnome-panel --replace` and the panel would appear a the bottom. Now it just crashes with `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. I also installed 22.04 on a brand new laptop with the same behavior.

Here is what I need `gnome-panel` for:

- I need a way to show the windows that live on my current workspace, and on my current screen (I have a dual screen setup) so that I can see them but also can switch to them in one click.
- It also serves as a startup icons bar, where I can put icons of installed apps and also icons customized to launch specific commands
- It can host a basic CPU/MEM/Net monitoring panel, and a visual clue as to which workspace I am on.

The deal breaker here is the first one as the sidebar will show me all apps, regardless of which workspace I am on. So any alternative software than `gnome-panel` that meets at least this requirement would solve my problem.

**Edit**: I found a workaround

Well, I didn't find a way to launch `gnome-panel` yet but foraging into the new Extension Manager, I installed `Window List`. While it's a step back from `gnome-panel` (It's a single purpose panel not customizable vs an all-purpose one with plenty of stuff one can add in it) it does the job well enough.

So, this is not really an answer to the original question, but it works well enough for now.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 uses a whole new different version of Gnome then 20.04. Do you know if this add-on works with the version of Gnome in 22.04?

Comment: AFAIK, `gnome-panel` is not an add-on. It's a core component of Gnome. It's the standard panels that act as taskbar. Obviously it doesn't work anymore, but it is still packaged in the standard Ubuntu repos leading me to believe it *should* work.

Comment: When I did a Google search it said it was part of an add-on pack.

Comment: Are you logged in to the gnome flashback session? On the default desktop, the launcher can be set to show only active windows from the current workspace.

Comment: @David Do you have the name of the add-on? I could not find it. The way I've been using it over the years is by running `apt install gnome-panel`. It's been working fine until 22.04

Comment: @vanadium Is there a possibility to have one launcher per screen? If I have two terminals - one on each screen - I need to be able to figure out which one I'm clicking on.

Comment: Yes, there is, and each of these can show the apps on the current workspace.